# Workspace exploration from urdf?

Tags: ros, kinematics, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Is there an easy way or a package to compute forward kinematics from an URDF file? The idea behind is to "explore" the workspace of a robot, plotting reachable points and dexterous area.

As far as I understand the document, TF is for tracking frames. KDL could do the tricks, but did not see if it is possible to use the URDF description of the robot to feed it.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75325/workspace-exploration-from-urdf?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot that I used is finally a RRR arm. So I wrote a code in Python that explores all possible solutions of the forward kinematic. That gives a big table (not that big either) and requests on this table are quite fast.

Here is the code on GitHub:

https://github.com/Arn-O/youbot-workspace-explorer

And a plot of the result:

http://zombiebrainzjuice.cc/first-result-youbot-workspace-exploration/

Example of request to solve inverse kinematics:

http://zombiebrainzjuice.cc/kuka-youbot-inverse-kinematics-simplified/

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) with karma: 107 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2017-05-08**:
Hey, has the github repo been moved?

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2017-05-08**:
Yes, I have removed everything some time at the beginning of the year

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something pretty similar to what you describe is available in the [moveit_workspace_analysis](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_advanced/tree/hydro-devel/moveit_workspace_analysis) package. I´m not sure it is actively developed/maintained (at least compared to the main MoveIt! packages), but it should prove useful when looking at a robot´s workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-10-02**:
The name looks very close to what I'm looking for. I did not find any documentation on the repo ... any idea where to find that? Google did not provide the answer.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-02**:
I fear the documentation is the code itself :) But given the quite good doxygen docs of MoveIt!, it´s quite possible to figure out what´s going on.